# Parameter type as object of custom class

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, parameters

Can I do in Lightning framework something like that:

```
public class MyController
public class Person{
        public String first_name{get;set;}
        public String second_name{get;set;}
    }
@AuraEnabled
public static String setPerson(Person p) {
System.debug('Person = ' + p);
return null;
}
}
```

My js controller:

```
var action = component.get("c.setPerson");
var person = {first_name: 'foo', second_name: 'bar'};
action.setParams({p: person });
//
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. That looks pretty much spot on to me, with the exception of the fact you have to declare the instance variables of your inner class as @AuraEnabled as well..

```
public class Person{
    @AuraEnabled
    public String first_name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String second_name{get;set;}
}
```

I believe you are roughly good to go then. If you have any problems, please post the specific error on here (which for best practise would be a new question) and we'll endeavour to help.